My port is always stuck in the old project
Long story short, I once worked on a project using port 8000. Now I want to create a new project with Laravel but when using PHP Artisan Server, my browser always redirects to the old project that was created. How can i resolved this?
I want to delete traces or reset all projects that use port 8000, so that I can work with that port for new projects
